# Enable an input filed when checkbox within corresponding label is checked

Tags: jquery

I wanted to enable/disable editing of the fields in a form based on its checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, its input has to be enabled and if not-checked, disabled. I had some script code for each field but am looking for a generic code instead of writing code for each field. Can anyone please help me achieve this efficiently using jquery.

```js
$('#nCheck').click(function() {
  $('input[name="Name"]').attr('disabled', false);
});
$('#pCheck').click(function() {
  $('input[name="Position"]').attr('disabled', false);
});
$('#oCheck').click(function() {
  $('input[name="Office"]').attr('disabled', false);
});
$('#aCheck').click(function() {
  $('input[name="Age"]').attr('disabled', false);
});
$('#dCheck').click(function() {
  $('input[name="sDate"]').attr('disabled', false);
});
$('#sCheck').click(function() {
  $('input[name="Salary"]').attr('disabled', false);
});
$('#phCheck').click(function() {
  $('input[name="Phone"]').attr('disabled', false);
});
$('#salCheck').click(function() {
  $('input[name="ProSalary"]').attr('disabled', false);
});
$('#phoneCheck').click(function() {
  $('input[name="ProPhone"]').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="userForm" name="modalForm" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="field-label">Name <input type="checkbox" id="nCheck"/></label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Name" id="person.name" value="Tiger Nixon" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Position" class="field-label">Position <input type="checkbox" id="pcheck"/></label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Position" id="person.position" value="System Architect" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Office" class="field-label">Office <input type="checkbox" id="oCheck"/></label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Office" id="person.office" value="Edinburgh" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="field-label">Age <input type="checkbox" id="aCheck"/></label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Age" id="person.age" value="61" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="field-label">Start date <input type="checkbox" id="dCheck"/></label>
    <input class="form-control" name="sDate" id="person.sDate" value="2011/04/25" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="field-label">Salary <input type="checkbox" id="sCheck"/></label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Salary" id="person.salary" value="$320,800" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name" class="field-label">Phone <input type="checkbox" id="phCheck"/></label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Phone" id="person.phone" value="123-456-7890" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-btn" id="getDataBtn">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Please refer the js fiddle mentioned below is my form html - https://jsfiddle.net/ycf6Ltad/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique you're looking for is called Don't Repeat Yourself, or DRY.

To achieve this you can extract the common parts of the logic to a single event handler, using class selectors and DOM traversal. Specifically using the `:checkbox` selector and the `closest()` method to get the parent `.form-group` before using `find()` to get the `input` you want to enable/disable. Try this:

```js
$('.form-group :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var $checkbox = $(this);
  var $group = $checkbox.closest('.form-group');
  $group.find('.form-control').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="userForm" name="modalForm" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="field-label">
      Name <input type="checkbox" id="nCheck"/>
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Name" id="person.name" value="Tiger Nixon" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="field-label">
      Position <input type="checkbox" id="pcheck"/>
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Position" id="person.position" value="System Architect" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="field-label">
      Office <input type="checkbox" id="oCheck"/>
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Office" id="person.office" value="Edinburgh" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="field-label">
      Age <input type="checkbox" id="aCheck"/>
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Age" id="person.age" value="61" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="field-label">
      Start date <input type="checkbox" id="dCheck"/>
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="sDate" id="person.sDate" value="2011/04/25" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="field-label">
      Salary <input type="checkbox" id="sCheck"/>
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Salary" id="person.salary" value="$320,800" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="field-label">
      Phone <input type="checkbox" id="phCheck"/>
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Phone" id="person.phone" value="123-456-7890" disabled/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-btn" id="getDataBtn">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that I amended the event from `click` to `change`, as it's preferred for use with checkboxes for accessibility reasons.

Also, I removed the `for` attribute on the `label` elements as it was actually breaking their functionality; as it didn't match the child element. It's not required when you wrap the `label` contains an `input` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Can you please let me know how I can read the value of a select box(yes/no) https://jsfiddle.net/ycf6Ltad/2/

Comment: I wanted to read the select box value on clicking savechanges button. Can you please tell me how. Please see the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ycf6Ltad/5/

Comment: There's no `select` in that fiddle, however you can use `val()` to read the selected option's value. If you have additional issues I'd suggest starting a new question as you're likely to get help quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).next('div.max_tickets').show();
else
    $(this).next('div.max_tickets').hide();
 }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div id="opwp_woo_tickets">
   <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][enable]">check1
   <div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][maxtickets]">
   </div>

   <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][1][enable]">check2
   <div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][1][maxtickets]">
   </div>

   <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][2][enable]">check3
   <div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][2][maxtickets]">
   </div>
         </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: I wanted to disable/enable editing of the fields. Please refer my jsfiddle mentioned in the question. I had some scrip code for each field but am looking for a generic code instead of writing code for each filed. Can you please help